# non printable characters in java

Tags: java, special-characters

Please, can you give me a list of non printable characters in java programming? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Retagged with hopefully better tags.

Answer (score 4):

Java uses the Unicode standard, so you should be asking about non-printable (non-printing?) characters in Unicode.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters

Answer (score 1):

Java strings are unicode strings. Unicode doesn't have a concept of "non-printable" characters, exactly, but the ASCII non-printable range, along with several other characters, are considered [Unicode control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters).

Answer (score 1):

Are spaces printable? What about the private use area? Please modify the code to your definition of "printable" :)

```
import static java.lang.Character.*;

for (int i=0; i<MAX_CODE_POINT; i++) {
    int t = getType(i);
    boolean p = t == CONTROL || t == CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION || t == CURRENCY_SYMBOL || t == DASH_PUNCTUATION || t == DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER || t == ENCLOSING_MARK || t == END_PUNCTUATION || t == FINAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION || t == INITIAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION || t == LETTER_NUMBER || t == LOWERCASE_LETTER || t == MATH_SYMBOL || t == MODIFIER_LETTER || t == MODIFIER_SYMBOL || t == OTHER_LETTER || t == OTHER_NUMBER || t == OTHER_PUNCTUATION || t == OTHER_SYMBOL || t == START_PUNCTUATION || t == TITLECASE_LETTER || t == UPPERCASE_LETTER;
    if (!p) {
        System.out.println("Non printable codepoint " + i);
    }
}
```